# Missing character in The Battlefield

Tags: lego-ninjago-movie

I am missing a character token in The Battlefield.  The map tells me it's below the castle, but I can't seem to find any way to move further down.

[image]

Where do I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain This token You have to destroy 5 barrels with weapons on the fortress wall.

Comment: This may be the solution (or it may not), but this answer is not descriptive enough.